# The --load-extension startup parameter does not work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, arguments

I'm trying to run chrome with the --load-extension startup parameter, I used to do it and the extension was loaded, but now I can't, it opens a tab with the contents of the extension folder instead of the extension

Maybe in new versions of the browser removed this feature?

Here is my launch example

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-extension "M:\Source\JS\MyExtension"

Comment: Use `=` instead of space after the parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really only needed to add "=" and everything worked ))))